# Close a dialog by pressing Enter

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I have a peculiar requirement:

I have a Create new object modal dialog with a number of fields and buttons OK and Cancel. I want the OK button to have focus, so the user can simply invoke the dialog and press Enter to create a new object with default values. I tried calling `requestFocusInWindow()`, but that doesn't work until the window is actually shown. I cannot call it after the window is shown, because the dialog is modal. And there is no method like `setInitialFocusedComponent()` on the dialog class.

OK, so then I proceeded to create a `KeyListener` for every field in the dialog (only 3 of them, no big deal), that would manually press the OK button if user hit Enter on them. The problem now is that the first field (and therefore the focused one) is a `JSpinner`, which consumes its own `KeyEvents`. So pressing Enter does nothing.

How can I achieve this "Enter to OK" behaviour on my dialog without reorganizing the elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things:

1. Have you tried using the setDefaultButton?: `dialog.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton)`
2. You could consider invoke your requestFocusInWindow() in an invokeLater.

Like this:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
     @Override
     public void run() {
         okButton.requestFocusInWindow();
     }
 });
```

Comment: +1, I liked the answer, How easy it is with Default Button :-). Just a side note from Java Docs - "The exact implementation of the default button feature depends on the look and feel. For example, in the Windows look and feel, the default button changes to whichever button has the focus, so that pressing Enter clicks the focused button. When no button has the focus, the button you originally specified as the default button becomes the default button again."